# Sorting text alphabetical order based on date

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array. The array contains timecreated in date formate & firstname in text formate. I have to sort 'date' first then sort 'firstname'alphabetical order. firstname will sorted alphabetical if the same date repeated.

e.g. If firstname F & C are same date then order will be C & F.

I tried this function to sort.

```
 function compareByName($a, $b) {
    if($a['timecreated'] == $b['timecreated'])
    {
    return strcmp($b['firstname'], $a['firstname']);
    }
    else{
    return $a['timecreated'] < $b['timecreated']; 
    }
}
    usort($a, 'compareByName');
```

This is the code:

```
<?php
$a = Array
(
    0 => array
        (
            "id" => 5305,
            'firstname' => "testb",
            "timecreated" => "08/07/2019"
        ),

    1 => array
        (
            "id" => 5304,
            'firstname' => "testa",
            "timecreated" => "08/07/2019"
        ),
2 => array
        (
            "id"=> 122,
            'firstname' => "John",
            "timecreated" => "01/14/2019"
        ),

3 => array
        (
            "id" => 85,
            'firstname' =>"Josh",
            "timecreated" => "01/07/2019"
        ),


4 => array
        (
            "id" => 62,
            'firstname' => "CAN",
            "timecreated" => "11/05/2018"
        ),

5 => array
        (
            "id" => 61,
            'firstname' => "CAB",
            "timecreated" => "11/05/2018"
        ),

6 => array
        (
            "id" => 59,
            'firstname' => "CAD",
            "timecreated" => "11/02/2018"
        ),

7 => array
        (
            "id" => 58,
            'firstname' => "CAR",
            "timecreated" => "11/01/2018"
        )

);


function compareByName($a, $b) {
    if($a['timecreated'] == $b['timecreated'])
    {
    return strcmp($b['firstname'], $a['firstname']);
    }
    else{
    return $a['timecreated'] < $b['timecreated']; 
    }
}
    usort($a, 'compareByName');
print_r($a);
```

My expected result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5304
            [firstname] => testa
            [timecreated] => 08/07/2019
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5305
            [firstname] => testb
            [timecreated] => 08/07/2019
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 122
            [firstname] => John
            [timecreated] => 01/14/2019
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 85
            [firstname] => Josh
            [timecreated] => 01/07/2019
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [id] => 61
            [firstname] => CAB
            [timecreated] => 11/05/2018
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [id] => 62
            [firstname] => CAN
            [timecreated] => 11/05/2018
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [id] => 59
            [firstname] => CAD
            [timecreated] => 11/02/2018
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [firstname] => CAR
            [timecreated] => 11/01/2018
        )

)
```

My result is not right. Please help ,thanks.

Comment: What is the result you are getting?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing the dates as strings, you need to turn them into `DateTime` objects first. Also, in order to get your result I had to change the string comparison order:

```
function compareByName($a, $b) {
    $time_a = new DateTimeImmutable($a['timecreated']);
    $time_b = new DateTimeImmutable($b['timecreated']);
    if($time_a == $time_b)
    {
        return strcmp($a['firstname'], $b['firstname']);
    }        
    return $time_a < $time_b;         
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/FnnVk)

Comment: Thank you @msg, This was really helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy if you use a special PHP class.

```
//class: https://github.com/jspit-de/tableArray
$assorted = tableArray::create($a)
  ->orderBy('DATEFORMAT("Y-m-d",timecreated) DESC,firstname ASC')
  ->fetchAll()
;
```